# Setting a default horizontal spacing value for math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Is there a way to set a default value for the horizontal spacing in LaTeX math mode? I'm constantly writing

```
$foo \; bar \; baz$
```

Where the `\;` macro sets the space that I am happy with. Is there a command I can add to my preamble so that

```
$foo bar baz$
```

displays as if those words were interspersed with `\;`?

Comment: space is ignored in math mode but if your real constructs are defined with appropriate math classes, then you shouldn't have to add space often. `\mathrm{foo} \mathbin{\mathrm{bar}} \mathrm{baz}` for example. Perhaps you should provide a complete document showing a real small example

Comment: If you always use 3 arguments, you could define a macro: `\newcommand{\myseq}[3]{#1\; #2\; #3}` or `\newcommand{\myseq}[3]{$#1\; #2\; #3$}` and then call it as `$\myseq{foo}{bar}{baz}$` or `\myseq{foo}{bar}{baz}`. Of course, some editors can help you with autocompletion.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as [XY-Problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean)!